# Refactor multiple if tests

Tags: refactoring, software

I have a class constructor that needs to perform a couple checks. It is checking a file for the occurrence of a few tags. I use a function that checks for the tags and returns a boolean value depending on whether the tag was found. If the tag was not found it calls `return`, stops executing the constructor and sets the `alive` flag to `false`. I cannot throw an exception in this case.

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
if (!tagExists(tag1))
    print(tag1 + " failed")
    alive = false
    return
if (!tagExists(tag2))
    print(tag1 + " failed")
    alive = false
    return
```

And this continues for the amount of tags there is. What would be the best way to refactor this? As I said, I cannot use exceptions.

Comment: Seems like you're doing a lot of the same things over and over.  Try a function. Might prevent silly mistakes like saying `tag1` failed when `tag2` failed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the natural way would be to write a loop. You could have an array of the tags and do something like this:

```
const Tag_t tags[NUM_TAGS] = { tag1, tag2, tag3 ... };
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TAGS; ++i)
{
    if (!tagExists(tags [ i ]))
    {
        print(tags [ i ] + " failed");
        alive = false;
        return;
    }
}
```